# Easily way to install dependencies linux

Tags: linux, dependencies, package

Someone know if there is any way to install dependencies on linux cross all distributions?

today we have a script for each distribution like:

`sudo apt-get install <dependencies>`
`sudo pacman -S <dependencies>`

the worst thing is that we can't just check the distribution and use the right package manager because in some distributions the packages names and sub dependencies are different.

I was thinking about if we have a repo that know the name for all packages cross distributions so we can check with distro and with packages are required to install a dependency